How to manually trigger a scheduled Cloud Function
I have to prepare dataset using big query,and send it through email in csv. I have created a triger to hit function on each 15th of every month. But how do i trigger this function, as i don't have any trigger, so do i use this cloud function.

Can you explain what your requirements are and about your infrastructure? Also share minimal replicating steps or the document you are following? Meanwhile check this Link1 and Link2.

I have to read data from big query and that as a report by email. This should be done automatically by cloud function using trigger.
